# Error al intentar hacer UPDATE con Angular y Nodejs/express

Tags: nodejs, angular, postgresql, express

En mi base de datos **postreSQL** tengo una **tabla books** donde hay un campo **state = true/false**. si esta en **true** siginifca que esta apto para la venta.
Con **Angular y nodejs/express** solo quiero setear esa propiedad **state = false**. Desde **Insomnia** me funciona, pero cuando lo hago desde **Angular**, **Nodejs/express** muestra en consola este error:

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token 1 in JSON at position 0
[1]     at JSON.parse ()**

¿qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Aca mi servicio **books.service.ts**

```js
bajaBook(id: number){
   return this.http.put('http://localhost:4000/books/baja/', id);
}
```

Aca **component.ts**

```js
darDeBaja(idBook: number) {
    this.bookService.bajaBook(idBook).subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res){
          console.log('Fue dado de baja');
        }
      },
      err => console.error('Error al dar de baja el libro ' + err)
    );
}
```

**Aca lo que tengo hecho en nodejs/express**

**books.controller.ts**

```js
export const bajaBook = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
  if (!req.params.id) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message:
        "FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO, falta el id de book",
    });
  }
   try {
   const idBook = parseInt(req.params.id);
    await pool.query('UPDATE public.books SET state = false WHERE id_book = $1', [idBook]);
    return res.json(`El libro con id ${req.params.id} fue dado de baja exitosamente!`);  
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json("error al intentar dar de baja el libro");
  }

}
```

aca la ruta **books.routes.ts**

```js
router.put("/books/baja/:id", bajaBook); // baja de libro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, cuando usas ExpressJS para obtener los datos de la consulta, `req.params.id`, siendo `req` un parámetro `express.Request` de la función de callcack del endpoint, espera que tu ruta tenga el bind de la variable:

```
router.put('/books/baja/:id', bajaBook)
```

Hasta aquí, todo bien. Sin embargo, el cliente REST está cargando la `id` como **body**, no como parámetro de la URL.

Esto es lo que tienes:

```
return this.http.put('http://localhost:4000/books/baja/', id);
```

La estructura de los parámetros de sobrecarga del método `put()` es:

```
HttpClient.put(url: string, body: any, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: "body";
    params?: HttpParams | { // Serán cargados como queryParams. Ejemplo: <URL>/?id=1
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: "json";
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable
```

Conclusión: Si lo que requieres es asignar la variable `id` como parámetro de la ruta, es necesario que especifiques la ruta **con** dicho dato:

```js
return this.http.put(`http://localhost:4000/books/baja/${id}`, { });
```

Como recomendación, ya que no envías datos en el cuerpo y el propósito del endpoint es **dar de baja** un libro, recomendaría que este sea configurado como `DELETE`, así es posible hacer la misma consulta sin cargar un objeto vacío:

```js
return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:4000/books/baja/${id}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en el lado de express. Tienes que enviar un json y sin embargo estas enviando un string.

Tienes

```js
res.json(`El libro con id ${req.params.id} fue dado de baja exitosamente!`);
```

Cuando debeería ser

```js
res.json({status: 'ok', message: `El libro con id ${req.params.id} fue dado de baja exitosamente!`});
```

Lo mismo en tu `catch`.

```js
 .json("error al intentar dar de baja el libro");
```